# UpdateFarmCredentials: PowerShell command line error?

Tags: powershell, user

```
stsadm –o updatefarmcredentials –userlogin "[DOMAIN\USERNAME]" –password "[PASSWORD]"
```

I've tried to run the above command with the " character and without, neither works.

The error is 'Command line error.'

This is syntax that's obviously worked without any problems in the past. Any idea why it's now throwing an error?

Worth noting - this is being in a an attempt to solve a problem with resolving a user profile application proxy. Is this user profile app called upon when this command is run?

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to use `stsadm` to change password of the farm account. With adminstrator credentials you can type:

```
net user user_name  new_password
```

With this you have changed the user_name password.

Reference: [How to Change User Password at Command Prompt](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/149427)